# Creating an easy search script with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I want an easy way to search 2 fields in my database.
Here is the scenario: form has text box called `name` which can submit a value to search script.

Search script checks `name` against first and last name fields in database.

Problem I have come across is if people have enter middle names in the database under the first or last name field.

Example of the data i want to search

```
fname        lname
--------------------
stephen      jones
john james   doe
john         james doe
```

I thought could do a search like this:

```
SELECT
_leads.Firstname,
_leads.Lastname
FROM
_leads
WHERE
_leads.Firstname LIKE '%stephen jones%' OR
_leads.Lastname LIKE  '%stephen jones%'
```

Well I was hoping it would work.

My other attempt was going to be to explode the string then compare that against the database.

Am I looking too much into this? Is there any easy short bit of code that would help me out?

Comment: I think you should count the number of words in the input, then based on number of words (2 or 3) you can write a proper query (include middle name or not)

Comment: select * from table WHERE firstname LIKE "john%" AND lastname LIKE "%doe"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search like this:

```
WHERE CONCAT(first, ' ', last) LIKE '%John%Doe%'
```

That would find it even when there are middle names :)

Comment: obviously t owuld be better to separate first and last name from query to look into first and last name in database :)

Answer (score 1):

You should probably set up FULLTEXT indexes on those two columns and use it to retrieve the rows. In MySQL you would then write:

```
SELECT * FROM _leads WHERE MATCH(Firstname, Lastname) AGAINST ('stephen jones')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT fields FROM table WHERE CONCAT(field1, ' ', field2) LIKE '%string%'
```